# How to join 3 tables in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 Tables

```
Item, Primary, Secondary
```

i want it to return `All columns` on Items and `Brandname` from Primary and `Size, Color`
from Secondary

ItemID - pk(item)
ItemID - fk(Primary)
ItemID - fk(Secondary)

i know how to do 2 tables but I'm having problem on how to do 3 tables

here's my code

```
From Item, Primary, Secondary
Where Item.ItemID=Primary.ItemID AND Item.ItemID=Secondary.ItemID
```

can someone point me out on my mistakes

just notice Primary is color blue is this a reserved words from access?

Comment: It would help immensely if you posted the structure and relations of the tables so we wouldn't need to guess.

Comment: To answer your question on reserved words.. Use prefixes for your object names.. so a table will be called tblItem and tblPrimary.

Comment: None of the answers at this stage will work in MS Access, Access is very fussy about bracketing joins, so you are far better off using the query design wizards if you are not sure what you are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since primary is a reserved word, surround the word primary with brackets []

[Edit to explain comment]
Using the query that @janet wrote, try adding an open paren before the item table and a closing paren just before the second inner join.

```
SELECT a.*, b.Brandname, c.Size, c.Color
FROM (Item a
    INNER JOIN [Primary] b ON a.ItemID = b.ItemID)
    INNER JOIN [Secondary] c ON b.ItemID = c.ItemID
```

Comment: yea i did use brackets for my primary and secondary to be safe but still something is triggering syntax error :(

Comment: When joining 3 tables, access gets confused sometimes. I think you might need some parentheses ()  around some of the joins. You can build the query with the gui then look at the generated sql.

Comment: +1 Access does not get confused, it *always* wants brackets for several joins (parentheses) :)

Comment: my friend somehow come up the codes
`SELECT Item.*, Primary.Brandname, Secondary.Size, Secondary.Color FROM (Item LEFT JOIN [Primary] ON Item.ItemID = Primary.ItemID) LEFT JOIN Secondary ON Item.ItemID = Secondary.ItemID`
and it finally work with left join :)
thanks anyways for the ideas guys

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
From Item 
  JOIN [Primary] ON Item.ItemID=[Primary].ItemID
  JOIN [Secondary] ON Item.ItemID=[Secondary].ItemID
```

Comment: here's my code but somehow it still syntax errors on FROM
`SELECT DISTINCT Item.ItemID, Item.ItemName, Primary.Brandname, Secondary.Color
FROM Item
JOIN Primary ON Item.ItemID=Primary.ItemID
JOIN Secondary ON Item.ItemID=Secondary.ItemID;`

Comment: based on other comments, primary is a reserved word in access ... a better table name would be the right way to go, or, bracket the names.  I modified the answer to show brackets.

Comment: That will not run in MS Access. Nor will any of the other examples at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT a.*, b.Brandname, c.Size, c.Color
FROM Item a
INNER JOIN Primary b ON a.ItemID = b.ItemID
INNER JOIN Secondary c ON b.ItemID = c.ItemID
```

The a, b and c are aliases for the tables in the query.  a.* will return all the columns from Items table.

Comment: i did what u said but still syntax error (missing operator) in query 'a.ItemID = b.ItemID
INNER JOIN Secondary c ON b.ItemID = c.ItemID'

Answer (score 0):

You should  try

```
SELECT Item.*, Primary.Brandname, Secondary.Size, Secondary.Color
FROM Item 
inner join Primary  ON a.primary_id = Primary.id
inner join Secondary  ON Primary.secondary_id = Secondary.id
```